# Access Core Data from multiple classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, appdelegate

I am using Core Data for the first time, and I am a but confused on a few things.

First let me explain the context of my app. It is essentially a virtual planner, like the kind that you had in high school/middle school with the times that classes start/end where kids are supposed to write their homework. I am trying to use core data to save around 11,000 of these period objects and query them to get the periods on a given day.

The problem that I am having is that I initialize my `NSManagedObjectContext` and `NSManagedDocument` in my AppDelegate so that the periods are loaded immediately once the app starts. I now want to query those period objects in the Core Data from a different class (DayView). How do I create a reference to the Core Data database from DayView.m so that I can query it? It seems weird to me to `[alloc init]` an instance of AppDelegate in order to access the property that I have for the `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Thanks for all of your help and I will be happy to clarify anything in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that in your application delegate. It's called the application delegate because it should do exactly those things involved in being the `UIApplication` delegate. It really shouldn't do any more than kick off the first view controller, if you're not using a storyboard, possibly opt into UI state restoration, and deal with distributing things like push notification tokens that arrive at the delegate.

Factor out your Core Data stuff into its own class. Have everyone else talk via that class. [The singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is a common way to prevent yourself from having to pass the instance of that class all over the place if it's a simple design fact that there'll be only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to do this is to *create* the NSManagedObjectContext (and it's dependancies) either when it's first needed or at application launch.

The NSManagedObjectContext is then *passed* to the first view controller, which then passes it on again to subsequent view controllers. This is what the Xcode Core Data templates do, and is the preferred way to do this.

This is covered in the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFAQ.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001802-242718), [Core Data Snippets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/stack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008283-SW1), and the [Core Data Release Notes for MacOS 10.7 and iOS 5](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/index.html). Of those three sources, the release notes document is the most current. From the release notes:

> Nested contexts make it more important than ever that you adopt the “pass the baton” approach of accessing a context (by passing a context from one view controller to the next) rather than retrieving it directly from the application delegate.

(And yes, you should be using nested contexts.)

Answer (score -1):

You don't allocate an instance of it; you can access the App Delegate & it properties with

```
    [UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

But I would suggest you save yourself some grief and create a data helper class that contains all your core data stuff.  It can be initialized in the App Delegate then referenced as needed from there.  I use this:

```
    dataHelper = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] dataHelper];
```

Then let dataHelper have all the code you need for core data access.